# reverse the axis of a subplot made using plotly

Tags: plotly

I am plotting 1 figure with 2 subplots (row=1, column=2) using plotly. I know that we can reverse the x axes of all the subplots using
`figure.update_xaxes(autorange="reversed)` but I want to reverse the axis of only my second subplot.

I tried `figure["layout"]["xaxis"]["autorange"]="reversed` and it reversed only the first subplot. inserting [:1] anywhere doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow [this section](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/#customizing-subplot-axes) on the documentation

Here I modify their example and I reverse the axes of the two first subplots, the first I reverse with the `autorange` property, the second I reverse by swapping the limits `[50, 10]` instead of `[10, 50]`.

```py
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Initialize figure with subplots
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=2, subplot_titles=("Plot 1", "Plot 2", "Plot 3", "Plot 4")
)

# Add traces
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[20, 30, 40], y=[50, 60, 70]), row=1, col=2)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[300, 400, 500], y=[600, 700, 800]), row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[4000, 5000, 6000], y=[7000, 8000, 9000]), row=2, col=2)

# Update xaxis properties
fig.update_xaxes(title_text="xaxis 1 title", row=1, col=1, autorange='reversed')
fig.update_xaxes(title_text="xaxis 2 title", range=[50, 10], row=1, col=2)
fig.update_xaxes(title_text="xaxis 3 title", showgrid=False, row=2, col=1, autorange='reversed')
fig.update_xaxes(title_text="xaxis 4 title", type="log", row=2, col=2, autorange='reversed')

# Update yaxis properties
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="yaxis 1 title", row=1, col=1)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="yaxis 2 title", range=[40, 80], row=1, col=2)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="yaxis 3 title", showgrid=False, row=2, col=1)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="yaxis 4 title", row=2, col=2)

# Update title and height
fig.update_layout(title_text="Customizing Subplot Axes", height=700)

fig.show()
```

[image: result]

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much!!

Comment: A positive comment is always welcome, thank you. Additionally you may follow the conventions here https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the 2nd subplot by the following:

```
figure.update_xaxes(row=1, col=2, autorange='reversed')
```